# how to get the plot of a slice fits cube in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a fits cube file and I want to get image of a slice using astropy. So I tried:

```
>>> from astropy.io import fits
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> hdulist=fits.open('\Users\...\MOS_017.Tb.fits')
>>> hdu=hdulist[0]
>>> plt.imshow(hdu.data[0,:,:],orgin='lower')
```

But then I am getting a memory error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.imshow(hdu.data[0,:,:],orgin='lower')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\decorators.py", line 515, in __get__
    val = self.fget(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\hdu\image.py", line 208, in data
    data = self._get_scaled_image_data(self._data_offset, self.shape)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\hdu\image.py", line 662, in _get_scaled_image_data
    data = np.array(raw_data, dtype=new_dtype)
MemoryError
```

I dont know what to do. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

From the astropy [website](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v0.3/io/fits/index.html),

> Working with large files
>   The open() function supports a memmap=True argument that allows the array data of each HDU to be accessed with mmap, rather than being read into memory all at once. This is particularly useful for working with very large arrays that cannot fit entirely into physical memory.

So, for your example the following should help,

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
hdulist=fits.open('\Users\...\MOS_017.Tb.fits', memmap=True)
hdu=hdulist[0]
plt.imshow(hdu.data[0,:,:],orgin='lower')
```

UPDATE: as data is scaled, maybe closing the file helps once data is extracted,

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
hdulist=fits.open('\Users\...\MOS_017.Tb.fits')
hdu=hdulist[0]
hdulist.close()

plt.imshow(hdu.data[0,:,:],orgin='lower')
```

Or instead,

```
 hdu = fits.getdata('\Users\...\MOS_017.Tb.fits')
 plt.imshow(hdu.data[0,:,:],orgin='lower')
```

Comment: ValueError("Cannot load a memory-mapped image: "
ValueError: Cannot load a memory-mapped image: BZERO/BSCALE/BLANK header keywords present. Set memmap=False.

Comment: Okay, not an expert on fits format but apparently memmap doesn't work with scaled image data. The original memory error is either because the file is too large for the available RAM on your system (see http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/appendix/faq.html#how-do-i-open-a-very-large-image-that-won-t-fit-in-memory), an error with the file header or maybe something elsewhere in your code. How big is the file? Can you extract sections and save/plot separately? I've added a few possible solutions which may help but if not, could you upload the fits file?

Comment: it did not help...there will be an obvious value error:ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: my file is about 350MB...I had another file of about 290MB size which work well using this program code. So i dont think there is any problem in the code.

Comment: If the bigger file causes problems then you may be running out of memory (check top/system monitor memory use while process is running) or the file is corrupt. Use http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/verification.html to check the file is okay. The files are not massive, are you opening more than one or other things in code? Verify My suggestion would be to try to convert the `MOS_017.Tb.fits` to remove the scaling so you can use `memmap` (see http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/fitsio.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved when i tried:

```
plt.imshow(hdu.data[0,200,:,:],origin='lower')
```

I am new to fits files so I am not sure about how it got right but I think it might be because my file in question would have dimensions=4.
I would be glad if someone could explain this.